# How do I change background image upon button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

Just want to click on button and have image that is on my desktop appear as background. I am using Tryit Editor v3.6

I tried various file paths with more/fewer enclosing folders, tried messing with ",',/,\ syntax...I just don't know enough

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">change background</button>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage ="/Users/mcgeheer/Desktop/testpic.png"
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage ="url( '/Users/mcgeheer/Desktop/testpic.png')";
```

Comment: Odds are your path is incorrect. Open your browser's dev tools and check for errors.

Comment: If this is an in-browser editor (I think Tryit is) you may not be able to do this with an image on your local machine. You might try an image from a website instead (like https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png, the google logo).

Comment: I'm using a mac; I left clicked on image file on desktop, Get Info, from there copied the file path...

Comment: ahhh..yes Michael that did it thanks!

Comment: So I need to learn how to load images to the website "stockpile" (since I dont know the technical name for it) of images which the code can access--is this correct?

Comment: @Randall I believe so, yes. I'm not sure exactly what the best practice is, but you could create an images directory in the same root as the script/html files, and make sure that the images are uploaded whenever the script/html files are (this is general advice, not specific to Tryit Editor).

Comment: Ok but in my case there will be hundreds of image files (which are maps of ancestor migration paths), so those I should probably load somewhere else and access the same way you suggested with the google logo?

Comment: I think so, yes. I think that would work.

Comment: @Randall share a serial of articles with you, it's about basic outline of web develop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web
we usually develop website locally(in our own computer), then put the production code and assets,...etc into a **server**. So others are able to access the website using browsers.

Comment: A copy of your desktop image will be saved at this address : %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles  (on windows machines) .. sometimes %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper . Try locating the image in the Themes folder and use that path..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a TryIt Editor from w3schools.

In that case, your file can’t be accessed from your filesystem due to browser security policy which is an advanced topi. You might have seen this kind of error in console while trying the above thing.

`Not allowed to load local resource: file:////Users/mcgeheer/Desktop/testpic.png`

I recommend to use image URLs which are available on google and not the images that are on your filesystem. Something like an eg.https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg

If you use something like this it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, note that you cannot use a local image if you are working on an online editor

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .background {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: white;
  }
</style>
<body>

<div id="background" class="background">Background</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">change background</button>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById('background').style.cssText = "background-image: url('http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/29800000/Blue-Rose-roses-29859433-449-300.jpg');"
    }
</script>
</html>
```